# Slave cannot connect to master in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 vps, on which i have installed ES. I try combine it to one cluster.
[image]

**master node** config

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  master:
    image: elasticsearch:8.1.1
    container_name: master
    environment:
      - node.name=master
      - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
      - network.host=0.0.0.0

  - discovery.seed_hosts=10.126.107.238:1029, 10.126.107.236:1029
  - cluster.initial_master_nodes=10.126.107.238

  - "node.roles=master"
  - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
  - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
  - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
  - "xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false"

mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
volumes:
  - master-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
  - 1028:9200
  - 1029:9300

volumes:
  master-data:
    driver: local
```

And **node01** config (data node)

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  node01:
    image: elasticsearch:8.1.1
    container_name: node01
    environment:
      - node.name=node01
      - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
      - network.host=0.0.0.0

      - discovery.seed_hosts=10.126.107.238:1029, 10.126.107.236:1029
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=10.126.107.238

      - "node.roles=data"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false"
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - master-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 1028:9200
      - 1029:9300

volumes:
  master-data:
    driver: local
```

When **node01** tries to connect to cluster - its raise error

> node01 | {"@timestamp":"2022-08-07T08:15:38.096Z", "log.level":
> "WARN", "message":"[connectToRemoteMasterNode[10.126.107.238:1029]]
> completed handshake with
> [{master}{5_tf1e03S4CYx_v4j4tTyw}{4LhWtmyPTaGKY5x_4Sf10g}{192.168.16.2}{192.168.16.2:9300}{m}{xpack.installed=true}]
> but followup connection failed", "ecs.version":
> "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[node01][generic][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.discovery.HandshakingTransportAddressConnector","elasticsearch.node.name":"node01","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elastic-cluster","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException","error.message":"[master][192.168.16.2:9300]
> connect_exception","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException:
> [master][192.168.16.2:9300] connect_exception\n\tat
> org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$ChannelsConnectedListener.onFailure(TcpTransport.java:1107)\n\tat